# Alternating row colors what am I missing

Tags: php, row, echo

I get no errors but no table is displayed, I know its not on prepared statements but there is no interaction its just a display so there is no chance of SQL injection

what Am I missing

Hello I have edited the long version

```
     <?php
echo "<table border='10' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #0099FF;'>";
echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";
echo "<td width='200' align='center'>NAme</td><td width='200' align='center'>Headhot</td><td width='200' align='center'>Date</td><td width='200' align='center'>Age</td>";
echo "</tr>";
include("dbopent.php");
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT N, Limg, Lpage, F, Age
FROM (
SELECT N, Limg, Lpage, F, Age
FROM (
SELECT N, Limg, Lpage, F, CURDATE( ) , (
YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) - YEAR( F )
) - ( RIGHT( CURDATE( ) , 5 ) < RIGHT( F, 5 ) ) AS Age
FROM ACT)alias
WHERE Age BETWEEN 30 AND 39)ALIAS
");


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
$color="1";
{
  if($color==1){
echo "<tr bgcolor='#000000'>";

echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['N'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . "<a href=\"{$row['Lpage']}\"><img src=\"{$row['Limg']}\">" . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['F'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
else {
echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";

echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['N'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . "<a href=\"{$row['Lpage']}\"><img src=\"{$row['Limg']}\">" . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['F'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

$color="1";
}
   }
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: What table are you selecting from? You have two selects and no table name?

Comment: the select statement is fine I just abbreviated its a long Age function with a lot of alias

Answer (score 0):

You write "SELECT SELECT".

P.S. And it is bad practice to mix PHP and HTML code. Look towards the MVC.

Comment: Could you add some context and explain why this works?

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that you don't have the FROM clause in your SQL statement. A valid query is as follows:

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE condition = something`.

You can define integers without the quotes: `$color = "1";` has to be `$color = 1;` Also, you are supposed to add it after the open curly bracket.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $color = 1;
   // rest of the code
}
```

Also please put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your script after the begin tag so it will display any errors on the screen.

You should also explain your issue in a better way, it's unclear what you want.

Comment: Indeed, but looking at the code it's not clear what he actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

Define color to 1... increase on each loop. do a modulus base 2 to see if there is a remainder and if there is it's odd then otherwise it's even.

```
$color = 1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$color++;
if ($color % 2 == 0){
    $outputColor = "#7b7b7b";
} else {
    $outputColor = "#fff";
}
echo "<tr bgcolor='".$outputColor."'>";

echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . "<a href=\"{$row['page']}\"><img src=\"{$row['img']}\">" . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
```

this doesn't repeat all that code that is unnecessary.. rather define the color and output it once...

However you should REALLY be using a css style since i didn't think all browsers support a TR with a background color.

Something like `echo "<tr class='".$outputColor."'>";`
and instead setting $outputColor to 'odd' or 'even'

then 
`.odd td {background-color:#7b7b7b}`
`.even td {background-color:#fff}`